# python matplotlib legend repeating

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a subplot with histograms. The plt.legend towards the bottom creates a legend where the colors repeat. In this screenshot of part of the subgraph,

"AROUSAL" is the same color as "SLEEP-REM"

[image]

How do I change the colors of the graphs and legend so that they are all unique?

```
def create_histogram( grouped, axs, df ):
    bin_size = 100
    alpha = 0.5
    grouped = df.groupby( 'Label' )

    bins = np.linspace( df.Capacitor_1.min(), df.Capacitor_1.max(), bin_size )
    series = grouped.Capacitor_1
    series.plot( kind = 'hist', title = "Capacitor 1", ax = axs[0][0] , bins = bins, alpha = alpha )

    ...

    bins = np.linspace( df.Mag_Z.min(), df.Mag_Z.max(), bin_size )
    series = grouped.Mag_Z
    series.plot( kind = 'hist', title = "Mag Z", ax = axs[3][2], bins = bins, alpha = alpha )

fig, axs = plt.subplots( nrows = 4, ncols = 3, figsize = ( 20, 40 ) )
fig.subplots_adjust( hspace = .5 )
grouped = df_left.groupby( 'Label' )
create_histogram( grouped, axs, df_left )
plt.legend( bbox_to_anchor = ( 0.98, 0.8 ) )
plt.show()
```

Comment: You define your own set of (cyclic) colours. Simple example at https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html , and available colours at https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#color .

Comment: @Evert your comment helped. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @Evert helped

> You define your own set of (cyclic) colours. 
>       Simple example at [matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html) , and available colours at [matplotlib.org/gallery.html#color](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#color) . – Evert

I modified pyplot like this above the function def:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

palette = ['#ff0000', '#663600', '#a3cc00', '#80ffc3', '#0088ff', '#d9bfff', '#a6296c', '#8c4646', '#ff8800', '#5e664d', '#269991', '#1d3f73', '#7e468c', '#d96236', '#7f2200']

# 1. Setting prop cycle on default rc parameter
plt.rc( 'lines', linewidth = 4 )
plt.rc( 'axes', prop_cycle = ( cycler( 'color', palette ) ) )
```

Comment: Shame you didn't copy the links as well.

Comment: Perhaps if you have now properly working code, you could add the lines where you defined your own set of colours to your answer? So that there's practical code in your answer.

Comment: Don't add the code to your *question* (since now the question doesn't make sense), add the code to your *answer* instead. Just the relevant two lines.

Answer (score 0):

`plot` has a `color` argument. You can use a distinct color for each column. For example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

n_columns = 4
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(1000, n_columns), 
    columns=['col{}'.format(i) for i in range(n_columns)]
)

df.col0.plot(kind='hist', color='b')
df.col1.plot(kind='hist', color='c')
df.col2.plot(kind='hist', color='g')
df.col3.plot(kind='hist', color='k')

plt.legend()
```